# Sendmail authenticating with DKIM but Roundcube is not authenticating

Tags: sendmail, dkim, roundcube, opendkim

So I have set up the mail server, Roundcube, and Sendmail both work as expected.

but many of my emails were going to spam in Gmail and others, so I was setting up the DKIM auth and it was successful.

**[Side Note]** for some reason, I set it up so SMTP uses port 25 instead of 587 (that other people recommended). So I don't know if that causes any issues.

First I tested it with Roundcube and sent an email to my Gmail account, when I click on the `See Original` section of the Gmail email, it doesn't show DKIM `'PASS' with domain mydomain.com`

But when I send in the terminal with Sendmail it does show under DKIM: `'PASS' with domain mydomain.com`

What am I doing wrong? Does Roundcube have a plugin to enable DKIM?

https://pastebin.pl/view/5d87eb76 <- that is the `Orignal Message` for both Sendmail and Roundcube.

Comment: From your description, we do not know whether the signature is missing, irrelevant or failing to validate. Show the headers (`From`, `Return-Path`, `Authentication-Results`, ..)

Comment: @anx https://pastebin.pl/view/5d87eb76 that contains the code for Orignal Messages for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out finally what the issue was, I had set up my DKIM and SPF, and DMARC with Sendmail. But Roundcube uses the "mail" command to send/receive mail. So I finally found that you have to go `config.inc.php` and set `$rcmail_config['smtp_server'] = '';`

That allows you to use Sendmail in Roundcube and DKIM and DMARC should work.